# Laravel after adding an input form I see a blank page instead of the view

Tags: laravel

I tried creating a shopping cart and pass in the data, So I made a button "add to cart" in my product page, after I pressed the button I did get redirected to /cart but I got a blank page instead of the view

```
{{ Form::open(['route' => ['cart.store'],'method' =>'POST']) }}
        {{ Form::submit('Pridať do košíka', ['class' => 'btn btn-success', 'style' => 'margin-top:15px;']) }}
    {{ Form::close() }}
```

Also, after adding an input so I could pass in the data in the button even the product page became blank!

```
{{ Form::hidden(['title','{{$post->title }}'])}}
```

this is my controller

```
  public function index()
    {
        return view('cart.index');
    }

public function store(Request $request)
    {
   Cart::add($post, 1)->associate('App\Post');

        Session::flash('Úspech', 'Úspešne ste pridali produkt do košíka');

        return redirect()->route('cart.index');
    }
```

my route

```
Route::get('/', 'LandingPageController@index');


Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

Auth::routes(['verify' => true]);

Route::get('profile', function () {
    return 'This is profile';
})->middleware('verified');

Route::get('/obchod', 'PagesController@getObchod');

Route::get('/product', 'PagesController@getProduct');

Route::get('/blogtest', 'PagesController@getBlogtest');

Route::get('/kontakt', 'PagesController@getKontakt');


Route::resource('cart', 'CartController'); 

Route::prefix('admin')->group(function(){

Route::get('/login', 'Auth\AdminLoginController@showLoginForm')->name('admin.login'); 
Route::post('/login', 'Auth\AdminLoginController@login')->name('admin.login.submit'); 
Route::get('/', 'AdminController@index')->name('admin.dashboard');
});
//produkty
Route::resource('posts','PostController');  
//kategorie
Route::resource('categories','CategoryController', ['except' => ['create']]);
//pouzivatelia
Route::resource('users','UserController');
//komentare
Route::post('comments/{post_id}', ['uses' => 'CommentsController@store', 'as' => 'comments.store']);
Route::get('comments/{id}/edit', ['uses' => 'CommentsController@edit', 'as' => 'comments.edit']);
Route::put('comments/{id}', ['uses' => 'CommentsController@update', 'as' => 'comments.update']);
Route::delete('comments/{id}', ['uses' => 'CommentsController@destroy', 'as' => 'comments.destroy']);
Route::get('comments/{id}/delete', ['uses' => 'CommentsController@delete', 'as' => 'comments.delete']);




Route::get ('shop/{slug}', ['as' => 'shop.single', 'uses' => 'ShopController@getSingle'])->where('slug','[\w\d\-\_]+');
Route::get('shop', ['uses' => 'ShopController@getIndex', 'as' => 'shop.index']);
```

I tried the same without the Form helpers, the result was the same.

I'm on laravel 5.7, and I'm using the laravelshoppingcart extension.

I'm pretty stumped, so thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Anything in the log?  Can you also post your route file?

Comment: @KST I added the route file, also where do I find the log? I did not get any error when viewing the pages, only a blank page

Comment: Can you also show the contents of CartController@index? edit: nevermind I see it.  How about the view `cart.index`?

The log is usually in `storage/logs`.

Comment: @KST cart.index is only html and css, I actually found some errors in the log file      [2020-01-08 23:18:54] local.ERROR: Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Cart' not found {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalThrowableError(code: 0): Class 'App\\Http\\Controllers\\Cart' not found at C:\\xampp\\code\\eeshoptest\\app\\Http\\Controllers\\CartController.php:39) , I will look at it closer tommorow.

Comment: My log file is pretty huge (3MB) so I don't know what to really look for, Also I assume I have to namespace Cart; in the controller for the above error, though that didn't fix my issue.

Comment: What is the code doing on line 39?

Comment: @KST  Cart::add($post, 1)->associate('App\Post');

Comment: Is your code on GitHub?  I'd be happy to take a look.  Other than that, make sure you also check the server logs.  I might suggest something like `tail -f /path/to/your/server/logs` and in another shell, `tail -f /path/to/your/application/storage/logs/[name_of_your_log].log` (Hint: after you execute a `tail -f` command, hit enter a few times so its easier to distinguish new output).  After you set those two up, try to reproduce the error and see if anything suspicious shows up.